# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting when inserting with parameters

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert an interger, a string and a list as a single record into  a database, but am striking an error.

Here is my code:

```
values=nprnd.randint(10, size=48) #NUMPY ARRAY
valuelist= map(None, values); #Convert to list
guid=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(20)) #Generate guid
for x in range(4):
    var_string = ', '.join('?' * 48)
    valuelist.insert(0,x)
    valuelist.insert(0,ent_guid)
    #50 coloums in table, guid, x and 48 randomly generated values
    query_string = 'INSERT INTO schema1 VALUES (%s,%d,%s);' % (guid, x, var_string) 
    cursor.execute(query_string, valuelist)
```

I keep getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 19, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query_string, valuelist)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
```

I know the cause of this error (Even SO has a few questions on the same error), but none of the solutions I've tried have solved this error for me

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: if you need to generate a guid, you should really use the uuid module... it's there for that purpose. I suggest `from uuid import uuid4; guid = uuid4().hex`

Comment: Unrelated to my current problem, but thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @navinpal indeed it is, but see my answer for the possible solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe MySQL-python uses printf format codes ('%s' for example) instead of '?' for placeholders. Try setting `var_string` like this:

```
    var_string = ', '.join(['%s'] * 48)
```

I also agree with [Endophage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432193/endophage) that `valuelist` appears to be too long. I don't think you need to insert `al` and `ent_guid`.

You also need to put quotes around the guid when you insert it:

```
    query_string = 'INSERT INTO schema1 VALUES (\'%s\',%d,%s);' % (guid, x, var_string)
```

Comment: Tried this... it gives me: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: Did you try it without the `valuelist.insert()` lines?

Comment: Can you try it with `%s` instead of `%d`?

Comment: This gives me a different error: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'EU4YMTVOLT5LLJ5IZ8UQ' in 'field list'") ..., where EU4YMTVOLT5LLJ5IZ8UQ is the generated guid

Comment: Updated. Try quoting the guid when it is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

After you generate your 48 '?'s you insert 2 more elements into valuelist, have you taken those into account? The following code will be more robust:

```
values=nprnd.randint(10, size=48) #NUMPY ARRAY
valuelist= map(None, values); #Convert to list
guid=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(20)) #Generate guid
for x in range(4):
    valuelist.insert(0,al)
    valuelist.insert(0,ent_guid)

    # moved this line and using len(valuelist)
    var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(valuelist)) 

    #50 coloums in table, guid, x and 48 randomly generated values
    query_string = 'INSERT INTO schema1 VALUES (%s,%d,%s);' % (guid, x, var_string) 
    cursor.execute(query_string, valuelist)
```

**Update:**

From you comment below, it sounds like you're trying to double insert the guid and x values, therefore, change the query_string assignment (with the other changes I also made above) to:

```
query_string = 'INSERT INTO schema1 VALUES (%s);' % (var_string)
```

This is safer than your current string interpolation as `cursor.execute` will ensure the values are appropriately escaped.

Comment: Tried that as well.... It give me the same error, hence tried assigning the guid and x seperately. In this case, it generates (guid,x,?[50]), but we need (guid,x,?[48]).... The whole table has 50 coloums, one guid (string), one x (int) and 48 other coloums (again, all ints).

Comment: This gives TypeError: not enough arguments for format string ... as we're passing only var_string but need to fill in the spaces for %s,%d,%s

Comment: @navinpai sorry, wasn't paying enough attention, it's now as I intended

Comment: I'm getting a: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're increasing the size of `valuelist` by 2 each time you go through the loop.

`valuelist.insert` adds a new item to the start of an existing list, so first time through the loop, `valuelist` contains 50 elements, then 52 the next, 54 the next, etc.

`query_string` only contains placeholders for 48 items though, so this will cause an error.

If you remove those lines, and change the '?' to '%s', you should have better results, e.g.:

```
for x in range(4):
    var_string = ', '.join('%s' * 48) 
    query_string = "INSERT INTO schema1 VALUES ('%s',%d,%s);" % (guid, x, var_string) 
    cursor.execute(query_string, valuelist)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try surrounding your values in single quotes in the query.

```
query_string = "INSERT INTO schema1 VALUES ('%s','%d','%s');" % (guid, x, var_string)
```